# jQuery - Getting index of sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Let's say I have a sortable list like this:

```
$(".song-list").sortable({
  handle : '.pos_handle',
  axis : 'y',
  opacity: 0.6,
  update : function () {
    var id = $(this).index();
    console.log("Moved to new position: " + id);
  }
});
```

When you move the list, it should update in console with the new position. The `.pos_handle` has no ID.. only the class.

How would I get the index of it's new moved-to position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the prepared `ui` object's `.item` property to reference the current element being moved:

```
update : function (event, ui) {
    console.log("Moved to new position: " + ui.item.index());
}
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/dfXHP/)

[jQuery UI Reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

Comment: I'm amazed at how you managed to find that in the doc. Still can't fin my way around to see those things, so the only way to inspect that is through exploration with Console.log()...